# Open a file in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, file

i wrote something in C to which needs to open a `file.txt` and manage some data. I have just started to use Eclipse (after Code::blocks and Netbeans) but i cannot find the right path to put my file in order to allow Eclipse to read it... any suggest?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define COD 10
#define DIP 1000
#define SIZE 5

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ora, minuti, i = 0, j = 0, min_lav;
    int num_dip = 0, trovato, dip_lav = 0;
    int vett_or[SIZE][SIZE];
    char cod_dip[COD+1], vett_dip[DIP][COD+1];


    FILE *fp;

    /* Apertura del file */
    fp = fopen (argv[1], "r");

    /* Verifica della corretta apertura del file */
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Errore nell'apertura del file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Primo caso */
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        /* Lettura dele righe e copia degli elementi in un vettore */
        while (fscanf (fp, "%d %d %s\n", &ora, &minuti, cod_dip) == 3)
        {
            strcpy(vett_dip[num_dip], cod_dip);
            num_dip++;
        }

        /* Stampa dei dipendenti */
        for (i = 0; i < num_dip; i++)
            printf ("Dipendente %d: %s\n", i+1, vett_dip[i]);

        /* Ricerca elementi diversi */
        for (i = 0; i < num_dip; i++)
        {
            trovato = 0;

            for (j = 0; j < i && trovato == 0; j++)
            {
                if (strcmp(vett_dip[i], vett_dip[j]) == 0)
                    trovato = 1;
            }

            if (trovato == 0)
                dip_lav++;
        }

        printf ("\n===================================\n");
        printf ("Ci sono stati %d dipendenti a lavoro", dip_lav);
        printf ("\n===================================\n");

    }

    /* Secondo caso*/
    if (argc == 3)
    {
        while (fscanf (fp, "%d %d %s\n", &ora, &minuti, cod_dip) == 3)
        {
            if (strcmp(argv[2], cod_dip) == 0) {
                vett_or[i][0] = ora;
                vett_or[i][1] = minuti;
                i++;
            }


        }

        /* Stampa del dipendente */
        if (i == 1)
            printf ("Per il dipendete selezionato è stato registrato un solo passaggio\n");

        printf ("Dipendente %s:\n", argv[2]);
        printf ("Primo passaggio: %d  %d\n",vett_or[0][0], vett_or[0][1]);
        printf ("Ultimo passaggio: %d  %d\n", vett_or[i-1][0], vett_or[i-1][1]);

        min_lav = ((vett_or[i-1][0]*60)+vett_or[i-1][1]) - ((vett_or[0][0]*60)+(vett_or[0][1]));

        printf ("Il dipendente selezionato ha lavorato per %d minuti\n\n",min_lav );

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the file name printed correctly in your error message (within the `fp == NULL` clause)?

Comment: "What is the 'best choice' (in your opinion) for a C/C++ IDE under Unix?" -- countless questions like this have been asked here, and closed for being subjective and leading to endless evangelizing. However, *my* suggestion is to **not** use an IDE in the beginning, but using a command-line compiler and simple text editor, because you want to learn **C**, not Eclipse / NetBeans / MSVC / ....

Comment: @simon the name is printed correctly yes...

Comment: @DevSolar i'm a newbie in programming... is it porrible to debugging on command line?

Comment: @user1409641: Absolutely. [GDB](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) is a fine and powerful debugger, and if you start it with `gdb -tui`, even provides you with a nice view at your source code while you set breakpoints and step through your code. While it might not *look* like much, I very much encourage familiarizing yourself with it, because it's second to none when it comes to C/C++ debugging. Command line might look like 70ies, but a good vim / gcc / make / gdb setup beats Eclipse CDT hands down in the long run. For Windows users, I recommend [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com).

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can't actually open single files that are not associated with projects (which can be quite annoying).

Create a project and add the file to it. Then you will be able to open the file ;)

EDIT: Okay, turns out I didn't read your question properly. Ignore this please :)

Comment: Thanks, how to add an existing file to my project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the text file you want to open in the Eclipse project's folder which is (probably) in your workspace folder (or call the function that opens the text file with the absolute path). If you create a new project you can see the path of your workspace folder in the new project wizard window.

Edit: Might be the solution to your problem [Read from file in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681059/read-from-file-in-eclipse)

> Did you try refreshing (right click -> refresh) the project folder after copying the file in there? That will SYNC your file system with Eclipse's internal file system.

Comment: i created a new project called "9.1" and it's correctly positioned in the "workspace" path... i put the "file.txt"in every directory under the "9.1" folder but simply Eclipse does not recognize any file.

Comment: Is the executable generated in the same directory as you also have your text file?

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. I have made a small project and placed a "test.txt" file in the project folder. Calling `fopen("test.txt", "r")` doesn't return `NULL` (built and run within Eclipse) and hence the file can be read w/o problems. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Well, i'm passing the file name through command line as "argv[1]" but nothing happens... have not tried opening a file with his name!

Comment: Please show your code. If you pass `argv[1]` you need to enter the file name under `Run > Run Configurations...` in the `Arguments` tab.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting in a call to `getcwd` to find the process' current directory?

```
  char dir[1024];
  getcwd(dir,1024);
```

Alternatively, could you specify the absolute path to the file?

Comment: Were i need to specify the absolute path?

Comment: How are you opening the file?  `fopen`?  Then instead of `fopen("foo.txt","r")` it would be `fopen("/home/me/stuff/foo.txt","r")`

Comment: yes i'm doing it correctly and i can open the file in the right way running it with (almost) every IDE except eclipse

Comment: So have you tried opening with an absolute path e.g. "/home/..."?